# public func for Array Balancing Point in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, methods, swift-playground

I was able to find the Balancing Point of an Array using Swift 3 Playgrounds. Now, I am trying to create a method (func) that will loop through the array and apply my code. Here is my code from Swift 3 Playgrounds:

```
import Foundation

let myArray = [1, 2, 5, 8, 4, 4]
let divSum = myArray.reduce(0, {$0 + $1}) / 2
print (divSum)
var myBalancePoint = Int()

if myArray[0] + myArray[1] >= divSum {
    myBalancePoint = myArray[1]
} else {
    if myArray[0] + myArray[1] + myArray[2] >= divSum {
        myBalancePoint = myArray[2]
    } else {
        if myArray[0] + myArray[1] + myArray[2] + myArray[3] >= divSum {
            myBalancePoint = myArray[3]
        } else {
            if myArray[0] + myArray[1] + myArray[2] + myArray[3] + myArray[4] >= divSum {
                myBalancePoint = myArray[4]
            } else {
                if myArray[0] + myArray[1] + myArray[2] + myArray[3] + myArray[4] + myArray[5] >= divSum {
                    myBalancePoint = myArray[5]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
print (myBalancePoint)
```

Comment: Is the balance point an array element or the *index* of an element?

Comment: In Swift 3 Playgrounds, my code above prints the Balance Point of 8. 8 is the value or element of Index [4] of the array. Keep in mind that, in Swift, the index begins at Index [0]. In other words, myArray has six indexes or indices.

Comment: Can you add your precise definition of "balance point"? Why does your code print `5` as balance point for `[1, 2, 5, 1, 4, 4]` ? What would be the expected output for `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and why? Can the numbers be zero or negative? – (And thanks for the reminder, but I happen to know how Swift indices work :)

Comment: The Balance Point is the integer value of an index that has the sum of the index integer values to the left of it equal to the sum of the integer values to the right of it. [1, 2, 3, 4] does not have a Balance Point. [1, 2, 5, 1, 4, 4] is showing 5 as the Balance Point because the divided sum (divSum) of the array is 8.5, which is a Double. Keep in mind that I am dividing the sum of the array by 2. Swift rounds the array's divided sum from the double of 8.5 down to 8 because we are dealing with Ints.

Comment: Because Swift rounded the double of 8.5 down to the Int of 8, the sum of the array is then represented as 16. The Balance Point is found in myArray's third index, which has the value of Integer 5. The value of Integer 5 is correct because 16 / 2 = 8. If you add myArray's first three indices, you get 8.

Comment: With all that being said ... is anybody on this site able to tell me how to put my working code as represented above into a working method (or function)?

Comment: Should the balance point of `[1, 2, 5, 1, 4, 4] ` be the 1 at index 4, because `1+2+5 = 8` (to the left) equals `4+4 = 8` to the right?

Comment: If myArray was an array of Doubles instead of Ints, then the Double 1.0 that would represent the value of the fourth index in your array would be the correct Balancing Point. However, myArray is an array of Ints.

Comment: `1+2+5 = 4+4` holds for integers as well.

Comment: Not when the Array of INTS is DIVIDED BY 2 in my second line of code. My second line of code applied to your array will result 8.5 for divSum. Swift rounds 8.5 down to 8 because it is an Int not a double in myArray. 8 is first achieved in index 2 if the array is [1,2,5,1,4,4]; thus, the correct computation of 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation:

```
func balancePoint(of a: [Int]) -> Int? {
    var leftSum = 0
    var rightSum = a.reduce(0, +)
    for (idx, elem) in a.enumerated() {
        rightSum -= elem
        if leftSum == rightSum {
            return idx
        }
        leftSum += elem
    }
    return nil
}
```

Example:

```
let myArray = [1, 2, 5, 8, 4, 4]
if let bp = balancePoint(of: myArray) {
    print("Balance point index:", bp, "Value:", myArray[bp])
} else {
    print("No balance point")
}
```

Output:

```
Balance point index: 3 Value: 8
```

How does it work?

```
    var leftSum = 0
    var rightSum = a.reduce(0, +)
```

are the current sum of all elements to the left and to the right of the current element, respectively.

```
    for (idx, elem) in a.enumerated() {
```

iterates through the array, setting `idx` to the current index
and `elem` to the current array element.

```
        rightSum -= elem
        if leftSum == rightSum {
            return idx
        }
        leftSum += elem
```

First subtract the current element from the right sum.
If left and right sum are equal then we have found the balance point.
Otherwise update the left sum for the next iteration and continue.

```
    }
    return nil
```

No balance point was found: return `nil`.

Comment: Thanks. Your code seems to be working in Playgrounds except for the following Error: "Use of unresolved identifier 'balancePoint'. I am trying to resolve that error. Any suggestions?